# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. Response code 500 error with Python Selenium Chrome In Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I installed selenium/standalone-chrome in docker, and the version is 4.1.2. But when I run my python code get bellow error:

[image]

My selenium/standalone-chrome in docker:

[image]

My python code:

```
def demo():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    )
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.quit()
```

Could anyone give me a favor on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by only adding this line to your code

```
options.set_capability("browserVersion", "98")
```

Answer (score -3):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:  Could not start a new session. ... Response code 500.
.
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=98.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v98.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=98.0.4758.48/) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 98

- But your *chromedriver* version is not getting detected.

> Driver info: driver.version: unknown

So most possibly there is a mismatch between *chromedriver version* and the *chrome=98.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=99.0* (as per [chromedriver=99.0.4844.51 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt)).